# Validate that original value was nil in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I want to add a validation to the model to check that a field (string) could be set to something only it's original value is nil.

How can I do this?

Actually two subquestions are:

- Is there a standard way of doing it
- If custom validation is required, how can I access original value (vs new value)

Comment: You might be able to abuse Ruby's `||=` operator in combination with Rails' `before_save` to accomplish this. If you're looking for a hard validation stop, then please note that `before_save` only runs **after** all the validations have run, so this might not do what you want.

Comment: @alephtwo Can you please post an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a custom job. Say you have a field named `field`.

```
validate :no_modifications_on_field

def no_modifications_on_field
  if field_changed? && !field_was.nil?
    errors.add(:field, 'Once you set a field, you can never change it!')
  end 
end
```

`field_changed?` and `field_was` are `ActiveModel::Dirty` helpers that get generated for every field. You can also access all changed attributes through `changed_attributes`.

Comment: I was writing up a post when this answer popped up, and it's exactly what you want to do.